# kubernetes pods spawn across all servers but kubectl only shows 1 running and 1 pending

Tags: kubernetes

I have new setup of Kubernetes and I created replication with 2.  However what I see when I do " `kubectl get pods'` is that one is running another is "pending".  Yet when I go to my 7 test nodes and do `docker ps` I see that all of them are running.

What I think is happening is that I had to change the default insecure port from 8080 to 7080 (the docker app actually runs on 8080), however I don't know how to tell if I am right, or where else to look.

Along the same vein, is there any way to setup config for kubectl where I can specify the port.  Doing kubectl --server="" is a bit annoying (yes I know I can alias this).

Comment: I can confirm that this has to do with me moving from 8080 to 7080.  I have no idea how to troubleshoot this, nor which point isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

If you changed the API port, did you also update the nodes to point them at the new port?

For the `kubectl --server=...` question, you can use `kubectl config set-cluster` to set cluster info in your ~/.kube/config file to avoid having to use `--server` all the time. See the following docs for details:

- http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_config.html
- http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_config_set-cluster.html
- http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_config_set-context.html
- http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_config_use-context.html